# Traverse template error and/or static assert 'pathway' in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In Visual C++, when a static assert is fired or there is a template error, doubly clicking on the error itself will take you to the actual template code and not the actual *erroneous* code that is trying to call it or instantiate it.

To see the code that instantiated it, you have to go to the `output window` and essentially *trace* the error by double clicking on the lines that contain a source file with the wordings `see reference to XXXXXX being compiled with`. This is all great, but when the templates are complex, it is terribly hard to find the source files in all the mess and double click on them. For example (I have changed the names so the error itself may not make sense, but this is usually what you get):

```
1>templateClass.h(390) : error C2079: 'STATIC_ASSERT'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            __formal=0
1>        ]
1>        filename.h(390) : while compiling class template member function 'TestClass<T>::TestClass(void)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=s32
1>        ]
1>        anotherFilename.cpp(131) : see reference to class template instantiation 'TestClass<T>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=s32
1>        ]
1>        yetAnotherFileName.cpp(149) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void Test_TestClass<T>(void)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=some_policy_class
1>        ]
```

So my question is this: **Is there a shortcut to traverse the error stack (is that the right terminology?) for a single error? A shortcut similar to CTRL+SHIFT+F12, which is *view next error*. Would be great if there is a shortcut for *view next file in error*.**